# Problem with sounds in XNA

Tags: xna

I get this error when I'm trying to play a sound in XNA: Error  1   Audio file cash-register.wav contains non-PCM data. What is PCM data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PCM stands for [Pulse-Code-Modulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation) and is a way to digitally represent analogue (sound) data. The problem you're having is that your WAV file contains invalid data. Did you just rename a .mp3 file to .wav? Or did you use a program to convert the data? If so you should check the converter settings and make sure that only the sound data is converted and that all meta-data is discarded.

Comment: No, I just downloaded it as .waw file! I got this problem with several files :(

Comment: You could try to open it in an audio editor end re-export is as wave (44100Hz, 16Bit is probably the most common format)

Comment: It is valid for a `.wav` file to contain data in a format other than `PCM`.

Comment: Andrew Russel is right (as usual ;) ) see the codec comparison section of this page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV it indeed lists a few other codecs though (L)PCM should be the most common.